# Adaptive Layout - calculate second row of views based on view width

Tags: ios, adaptive-layout

I am programmatically adding a dynamic number of `UIButton` which are labeled as hashtags to a compact view using Adaptive Layout. Is there a way for adaptive layout to automatically calculate when the width of the view is met and a new line is needed, or do I need to calculate that myself, then manually anchor the next row of buttons under the previous and so on?

My current source gives me the following image, where a second row is needed. Appreciate any direction on this.

[image]

Comment: You could try using a `UICollectionView` and the default flow layout would handle that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto layout cannot do this, so if you want to use individual buttons, you'll have to calculate it yourself. Another alternative would be to use a collection view which will automatically layout the buttons (cells).